# launch github on docker container

Tags: git, docker, github

I cannot found a docker image of github, any idea why?

I need an image of a git server who do the same jobs than github:

1. do version control repository
2. have an http web site
3. propose the same API than github (in order to use some jenkins plugin planned to  use github)

gitolite doesn't meet requirement #2

gitlab doesn't meet requirement #3

Any Idea?

Comment: So you want to host a private github using docker?

Answer (score 0):

There are some products that are very similar to github, that have official docker images

1. [bitbucket](https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/bitbucket-server/)
2. [gitlab](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/)

Answer (score 0):

> docker image of GiTHub, any idea why?

Because a GitHub "on premise" (that is, that you can host yourself) is called... [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/home), and is more suite to [a VM environment](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.10/admin/guides/installation/provisioning-and-installation/)

You can look at **[gogs](https://github.com/gogits/gogs)**:

- it has a [docker installation](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/tree/master/docker)
- and it support some level of GitHub-API compatibility through [`gogits/go-gogs-client`](https://github.com/gogits/go-gogs-client) (with [PR 52 as an illustration](https://github.com/gogits/go-gogs-client/pull/52))

Comment: How do you use go-gogs-client?

Comment: @sab it is a Git repo hosting server. You just kaunch it.https://github.com/gogits/gogs#installation and https://github.com/gogits/gogs#tutorials

Comment: I've already install gogs, but it don't expose anything like the api/v3. api/v3 who is expose by gogits/go-gogs-client. I search a way to use both gogs and gogits/go-gogs-client.

Comment: @sab the project go-gogs-client is still in its early stage, and the installation isn't clear yet;) https://github.com/gogits/go-gogs-client/issues/75. I supposed it is meant to be compiled with Gogs itself.